# Mean and variance of a function of a (continuous) random variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am interested in calculating the mean and the variance of a (univariate continuous) random variable whose density function can be actually expressed as a transformation of the density function of another random variable; more precisely, it happens to be a transformation of the doubly noncentral $F$ distribution (`NoncentralFRatioDistribution` in Mathematica).

As an example, if I try this:

```
Mean[NoncentralFRatioDistribution[7, 3, 0, 0.5]]
```

I get:

```
2.54662
```

But if I try this:

```
dist1 := ProbabilityDistribution[Sqrt[PDF[NoncentralFRatioDistribution[7, 3, 0, 0.5], x]],
  {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, Method -> "Normalize"]
```

and then I ask for the mean of this transformed variable:

```
Mean[dist1]
```

I get:

```
Mean[ProbabilityDistribution[
  0.188114 Sqrt[
   PDF[NoncentralFRatioDistribution[7, 3, 0, 
     0.5], \[FormalX]]], {\[FormalX], 0, \[Infinity]}]]
```

**Is it that the expected behaviour of Mathematica 11.1? Am I doing something wrong? What else can I try?**

Comment: As shown in the answers below, one applies the transformation to the random variable and not the density function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, we define your distribution using [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html):

```
dist1 = TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[x], x \[Distributed] NoncentralFRatioDistribution[7., 3., 0., 0.5]]
```

Now, we can get the mean using [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html):

```
N@Mean@dist1
(* 1.23037 *)
```

Comment: Wow! I still have to read it twice, but thank you!

Comment: There is also the shortcut `NExpectation[Sqrt[x],  x \[Distributed] NoncentralFRatioDistribution[7., 3., 0., 0.5]]`.

Comment: @Mathe172 Why is `N@Mean` working better than the sentence `Mean` (at least in the examples I've been trying)?

Comment: @Vicent I wondered about that myself... I assume MMA somehow wants to give you an "exact" result, which it cannot do. `N` forces it to evaluate it numerically, which gives it more freedom in what to do. But this is just a guess - I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = NoncentralFRatioDistribution[7, 3, 0, 0.5];
td = TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[x], x \[Distributed] f];
```

You can simulate:

```
rv = RandomVariate[td, 100000] // Mean
rvf = Mean@Sqrt[RandomVariate[f, 100000]]
```

or explicitly calculate:

```
NIntegrate[x PDF[td, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

or use `N@Mean@td`

Outputs: 1.236, 1.22386, 1.23037, 1.23037